# What Null hypothesis does vegan::anova.cca(by = "terms") test against?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, anova, vegan

I ran a distance-based Redundancy Analysis with the vegan R-package. 
Statistical significance of axes and explanatory variables can be tested with the anova.cca() function.

Form Legendre et al. 2011, I know that the test of the individual axes tests "The null hypothesis for the test of significance of the jth axis is H0: the linear dependence of the response variables Y on the explanatory variables X is less than j-dimensional". 
But what is the null hypothesis when testing environmental variables?

-- 
Legendre, P., Oksanen, J., & ter Braak, C. J. F. (2011). Testing the significance of canonical axes in redundancy analysis. Methods in Ecology and Evolution, 2(3), 269–277.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The null hypothesis changes as the sequence of models is tested.  Say we have three terms to be tested `A`, `B`, and `C` and we fit the model as `Y ~ C + A + B`. We test the following sequence of models

1. `Y ~ C`
2. `Y ~ C + A`
3. `Y ~ C + A + B`

with the corresponding models being the null against which each of those models is tested against

1. `Y ~ 1`
2. `Y ~ C`
3. `Y ~ C + A`

If were turning this into words, then we have variations on:

1. H0 for model 1: the effect of `C` on `Y` is equal to 0
2. H0 for model 2: the effect of `A` on `Y` *after* accounting for the effect of `C` on `Y`, is equal to 0.
3. ...

and so on.

Comment: Thanks!  Is there an option to makes this independent of order? So that each variable would be tested against the model where both other variables are already fit.

Comment: Double check with the help page, but I believe that is what it done when you use `by = "margin"`